# Matching specific values from separate CSV files and concatenating the rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I am trying to create a python v3.x program that looks at 2 CSV files.
Initially I need to separate the CAR CSV list into 2 lists, Expensive Cars and Cheap cars and assign the relevant rows to each.

I'm then planning on taking an indicator from the Indicator CSV, seeing whether it's an indicator specific to either an expensive car, cheap car, or both, and then concatenating the values from that Indicator CSV row, with a matching row in the Car CSV.

> 1. CAR CSV - Lists details on a number of cars
>
>    "Car code","Price","Alias","Groups"
>      "Car1","100","Blue Car","Cheap Cars"
>      "Car2","900","Gold Car","Expensive Cars"
>      "Car3","150","Red Car","Cheap Cars"
>      "Car4","999","Platinum Car","Expensive Cars"
>      "Car5","122","Brown Car","Cheap Cars"
>      "Car6","500","Pink Car","Cheap Cars","Expensive Cars"
> 2. Indicator CSV - Lists possible faults/errors with cars
>
>    "Indicator_Field","Indicator_Value","Desc","Groups"
>      "Fault","Rusting","Bodywork is rusting","Cheap Cars; Expensive Cars"
>      "Error","Window Winder Stopped","Manual window winder broken","Cheap Cars"
>      "Fault","V12 Issues","V12 Engine Problems","Expensive Cars"
> 3. Concatenated Examples
>
>    {"code":"Car1","Error":"Rusting"}
>      {"code":"Car2","Fault":"V12 Issues"}
>      {"code":"Car5","Error":"Window Winder Stopped"}
>      {"code":"Car1","Error":"Window Winder Stopped"}

So far all I have been able to do is select a random line from each CSV and concatenate specific values from each. The problem is that now all indicators and car groups match up.

```
from sys import argv
from time import sleep
import random
import csv
import heapq

script, indicator_file, car_file = argv
ind = ''
car = ''

def indicatorDefinition(i):
    with open(i) as file:
        reader = csv.DictReader(file)
        random_line, = heapq.nlargest(1, reader, key=lambda L: random.random())
        global ind
        ind = random_line['Indicator_Field']+'":"'+random_line['Indicator_Value']+'"'

def carDefinition(n):
    with open(n) as file:
        reader = csv.DictReader(file)
        random_line, = heapq.nlargest(1, reader, key=lambda L: random.random())
        global net
        net = '"code":"'+random_line['Car code']+'","'




def counter():
    count = 0
    while count < 6:
        carDefinition(car_file)
        indicatorDefinition(indicator_file)
        print("{"+car+ind+"}")
        sleep(random.randint(1,10))
        count += 1


counter()
```

Comment: Are you open to use pandas?

Comment: @AntonvBR yeah if that will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this, maybe? <del>I assumed the Groups field should be split and not used as-is.</del> Updated according to comments to read all groups.

```
import csv
import io
import random
import collections
import itertools

# Data included in source for clarity

car_csv = """
"Car code","Price","Alias","Groups"
"Car1","100","Blue Car","Cheap Cars"
"Car2","900","Gold Car","Expensive Cars"
"Car3","150","Red Car","Cheap Cars"
"Car4","999","Platinum Car","Expensive Cars"
"Car5","122","Brown Car","Cheap Cars"
"Car6","500","Pink Car","Cheap Cars","Expensive Cars"
"TestCarWithThreeGroups","500","Pink Car","Cheap Cars","Expensive Cars","Broken Cars"
""".lstrip()

indicator_csv = """
"Indicator_Field","Indicator_Value","Desc","Groups"
"Fault","Rusting","Bodywork is rusting","Cheap Cars; Expensive Cars"
"Error","Window Winder Stopped","Manual window winder broken","Cheap Cars"
"Fault","V12 Issues","V12 Engine Problems","Expensive Cars"
""".lstrip()

# Read data (replace io.StringIO(...) with a file object to read from a file)
indicator_data = list(csv.DictReader(io.StringIO(indicator_csv)))

# Note `restkey` to capture all of the additional columns into `OtherGroups`.
car_data = list(csv.DictReader(io.StringIO(car_csv), restkey='OtherGroups'))

# Pre-massage the car data so `Groups` is always a set of groups, and `OtherGroups` is no longer there:
for car in car_data:
    car['Groups'] = {car['Groups']} | set(car.pop('OtherGroups', ()))


# Create a mapping of groups <-> indicators
indicators_by_group = collections.defaultdict(list)
for indicator in indicator_data:
    for group in indicator['Groups'].split('; '):
        indicators_by_group[group].append(indicator)


def generate_car():
    car = random.choice(car_data)
    # Concatenate all indicators based on the groups of the car
    available_indicators = list(itertools.chain(
        *(indicators_by_group.get(group, []) for group in car['Groups'])
    ))
    # Choose a random indicator -- this will crash if there are no available indicators
    # for the car.
    indicator = random.choice(available_indicators)
    # Generate output datum
    return {
        'code': car['Car code'],
        indicator['Indicator_Field']: indicator['Indicator_Value'],
    }


for x in range(10):
    print(generate_car())
```

example output:

```
{'code': 'Car1', 'Error': 'Window Winder Stopped'}
{'code': 'Car6', 'Error': 'Window Winder Stopped'}
{'code': 'Car2', 'Fault': 'Rusting'}
{'code': 'Car6', 'Error': 'Window Winder Stopped'}
{'code': 'TestCarWithThreeGroups', 'Error': 'Window Winder Stopped'}
{'code': 'Car5', 'Fault': 'Rusting'}
{'code': 'Car2', 'Fault': 'Rusting'}
{'code': 'TestCarWithThreeGroups', 'Fault': 'V12 Issues'}
{'code': 'Car6', 'Fault': 'Rusting'}
{'code': 'TestCarWithThreeGroups', 'Error': 'Window Winder Stopped'}
```

Comment: That's perfect, however after further investigation of the Cars.csv the example I gave was incorrect :( It seems that rather than seperating the groups like it does in the indicators with a ; the cars csv puts it into a new value ,"group2"

Comment: If you update your original post with the actual data format here, I can make the relevant changes to the code.

Comment: Change has been made, Car6 of the Cars CSV note how the 2 car groups are separated. Thanks for you help btw.

Comment: Thank you so much!! That works perfectly, i think my main issue is where I'm so new to this I don't know all the different ways you can approach things yet.